# Laravel shows error in "localhost:http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, server, localhost

I used Laravel in Visual Studio code, and when I opened `localhost:http://127.0.0.1:8000/` bypassing command `php artisan serve`, I got an error.

So I used another command `php -S localhost:8888 -t public`, I used this 8888 localhost. But I can't understand why `localhost:http://127.0.0.1:8000` is not working.

This is an image of a browser:

[image: this is image of browser]

[image]

Comment: what is your error when you use php artisan serve ?

Comment: I upload image below question

Comment: another solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574906/php-unknown-failed-opening-required-on-line-0-laravel-5-6 please try this to solve

Comment: Whatever command you use in Visual Studio to run your localhost:8000 probably doesn't use `public` as the document root

Comment: why?can't use public

Comment: Do not use Xampp (denwer, mamp, and etc.) in 2020. 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead

Comment: check if your server.php file is present in the given location as mentioned in the warning

Comment: Re-check your `.env` file has the correct parameters . Also the check if you have already run a laravel project instance in the same port . Also try to clear your browser history and then try to run `php artisan serve` or `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` .

Answer (score 0):

you need to go at your laravel project path and run cmd after that run this command.

Another solution is here
[php - Unknown: Failed opening required on line 0. laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574906/php-unknown-failed-opening-required-on-line-0-laravel-5-6)

Comment: I did that,but it's not working.I got an error on server http://127.0.0.1:8000. PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.
 PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: But I am not using avast antivirus

Comment: php artisan serve --port=8000 try this

Comment: I try your solution but still, it's not working, showing same error

Comment: can you share screenshot of cmd?

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot of cmd

Comment: is server.php file inside blog folder or not?

Comment: yes, there is an issue in server.php file, but I can't understand. So  I reinstall laravel and error gone.